# How to move a Skin Object Control with Resources to a DNN Module and building the module without namespace errors?

Tags: namespaces, dotnetnuke

I have created a DotNetNuke module with code I have copied from a skin file (Skin Object).
I am trying to make this a module so that I can drop it on any page and move and manipulate it any way I like.

I have managed to get the module to work, but only after it failed to find the tagprefix after installing the module and refreshing the page.

The problem is that Visual Studio is complaining that it can't find the namespace, but these resources are defined in the skin file.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="/Admin/Skins/language.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGIN" Src="/DesktopModules/LoginSkinObject/ParrotLoginSkinObject.ascx" %>

<div class="loginlinkwrapper">
<em class="fa fa-user"></em><dnn:USER runat="server" id="dnnUSER" CssClass="login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <em class="fa fa fa-lock"></em><dnn:LOGIN runat="server" id="dnnLOGIN" CssClass="login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" id="dnnLANGUAGE"  showMenu="False" showLinks="True" />
</div>
```

I just need a way for Visual Studio to build the module without complaining about the namespaces.

This is the error I get in the Output window (Please note that we only have our DesktopModules in VS to keep everything neat:

[image]

This is where the Resources are already defined in the Skin File.
[image]

Now, I did try to copy the resources from DNN and adding it to the Project, but for some reason it can't find it. Is there perhaps a web.config setting I can add?

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you're not doing the references with ~

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="~/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/language.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGIN" Src="~/DesktopModules/LoginSkinObject/ParrotLoginSkinObject.ascx" %>
```

You also should double check that IIS doesn't have an application/virtual directory on the /desktopmodules/ folder as that can sometimes happen and cause problems.

Another thing you might try is simply close the ASCX files when you build, and see if Visual Studio stops chirping about them.

Comment: I have tried to add ~, but it makes no difference as these references to the files is in another folder...so it will not really find it when building these modules. My development branch is totally separate from my website root, so it will never find the paths to these files. When I copy and install the files, I have a batch file which will delete the virtual directories in IIS. I install the modules manually as my Install.zip files are built in a separate folder. For some reason I never get an error for labels <%@ Register TagName="label" TagPrefix="dnn" Src="~/controls/labelcontrol.ascx" %>

Comment: If you're doing the development outside of my recommended dnndev.me development install/structure I can't provide any recommendations. Over my many years of DNN development, I believe using my approach is the easiest, and most efficient way to do DNN development.

Answer (score 1):

When referencing these skin objects like this inside of a DNN Module it can get really complicated as Visual Studio doesn't know where to go find the type of the referenced element.

Typically, if you go into your .designer.cs file you will see that the element gets tagged as a Generic control of some type, you will need to modify this to reflect the proper type/namespace reference for the controls.  This additionally does require DLL references as part of this, so be cautious for circular references depending on how you have things architected.

This isn't an issue for the skins, as they are not using a code-behind file and are processing these truly dynamically by loading the referenced src attribute.